# What does the error when trying to add a document url to content type mean?

Tags: error, content

Visual Studio 2010 gives me this error,

> urlOfFile - Parameter name: Specified value is not supported for the
>   urlOfFile parameter.

by the following line of code.

```
// Specify a document template.
templateDocumentCType.DocumentTemplate = documentTemplate;
```

The code is taken directly from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460224.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the stacktrace I found out the error was inside `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.get_Item(String urlOfFile)`. And the solution was to use an absolute url instead of only the filename for the property setter.

Comment: To be more precise: the URL should be either an absolute URL, a server-relative URL, or *relative to the content type resource folder for the content type*.

Comment: I think I tried the server-relative URL without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when remote provisioning my SP Online via xml template and pnp engine.

I finally used the absolute URL using {sitecollection}.

```
<pnp:Files>
       <pnp:File Src=".\Assets\MyDocTemplate.docx" Folder="{sitecollection}/_cts/MyContentTypeName" Overwrite="true"/>
</pnp:Files>
<pnp:ContentTypes>
 <pnp:ContentType ID="MYGUID">
   <pnp:DocumentTemplate TargetName="{sitecollection}/_cts/MyContentTypeName/MyDocTemplate.docx"/>

        </pnp:ContentType>
</pnp:ContentTypes>
```

Hope this helps.